# Where are Windows XP toolbars defined?

Tags: windows-xp, toolbar

I'm trying to find where the Windows XP taskbars are defined. I don't think it is in the registry as I've:

- created a new folder called "_ZYX_Searchable" and added a new toolbar.
- searched the registry for this string and found no results.
- I've also searched the entire "c:" drive in case it has created a ".lnk" file somewhere but not found anything.

Can any one point me in the right direction?
G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP (at least) appears to store the position and link information for the taskbar icons and toolbars in the following key:

> `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Desktop]
>   "TaskbarWinXP"`

It's encoded as REG_BINARY so appears as a string of hex in a registry editor.

Comment: Ah! This looks like it might be what I was looking for. THank you for trawling the ancient questions :-) 

Now, I just need to remeber why I wanted this info in the first place :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link will give some insight

https://web.archive.org/web/20181229071714/http://www.realgeek.com/forums/toolbar-registry-entries-220100.html

.

Comment: URL no longer works

Comment: Fixed link.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about WinXP, but Win7 creates them in:

C:\Users\(userName)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\(toolbarName)

so maybe this will help

Comment: "C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" does contain the quick launch folder but ONLY the quick launch folder. This does not contain other folders or links to them.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful if you could explain what you're trying to accomplish.  If you created a new taskbar toolbar, you would find its contents in the folder you specified when you created the toolbar.  Some toolbars exist only as objects in the registry.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but what I am trying to acertain is where in the registry this data is stored. The purpose of this question (if I remember rightly) was to be able to back up these settings and transfer them to a new machine or profile on the same machine. G

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to find out where Quick Launch settings placed on the Windows Status bar at bottom of the screen where you have the Start Button are saved then go to the folder:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\[UserName]\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch
```

Comment: this is not what I was looking for. Umber Ferrule's answer was what I needed. Thanks